# RtlStringCbCopy Function of the Windows Driver Kit

Tags: winapi, driver, device, wdk

According to the MSDN documentation, the RtlStringCbCopy safe string function should be like this:

```
NTSTATUS RtlStringCbCopy(
  __out  LPTSTR pszDest,
  __in   size_t cbDest,
  __in   LPCTSTR pszSrc)
```

But when I compile my code the ddk says:

> 1>c:\work\mydevdrv\loopback\driver.cpp(421)
>   : error C2664: 'RtlStringCbCopyW' :
>   cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'LPTSTR' to 'NTSTRSAFE_PWSTR' Linking
>   Executable - i386\loopback.sys 1>link
>   : error LNK1181: cannot open input
>   file 'c:\work\mydevdrv\loopback\objchk
>   _wxp_x86\i386\driver.obj' BUILD: Finish time: Tue Apr 19 20:21:51 2011

It seems that it is expecting the first argument to be of type NTSTRSAFE_PWSTR instead of LPTSTR.  But this NTSTRSAFE_PWSTR type is never mentioned in the MSDN doc.  So which type should I use?

My call to this function is like this:

```
RtlStringCbCopyW((LPTSTR)pIrp->UserBuffer, 1024 ,L"return value from driver");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call is wrong.

This should read :

```
RtlStringCbCopyW( (wchar_t*) pIrp->UserBuffer, 1024 ,L"return ...");
```

This is due to the fact, that the 'T' in LPTSTR means 'dependent on unicode build'. Kernel mode drivers do not use this. You always should know with what strings you really work and should not depent on the 'unicode' hack in the win32 api.

NB: Win32 does the 'T' type mapping, by having all (/most) functions in 2 variants. The W and the A version (DrawTextA/DrawTextW). The version which the comipler will then resolve to when calling the non-postfix version is to just define the function name to the corresponding version. (DrawText resolves to either DrawTextA or DrawTextW). This is not very robust, and should better be bypassed in your code by using the right function for the string you want to pass.

---

`NTSTRSAFE_PWSTR` is defined as following :

```
typedef __nullterminated wchar_t* NTSTRSAFE_PWSTR;
```

The `__nullterminated` is used by the prefast tool to check parameters. Prefast is a static code analyzer. In this context it probably means 'the output is guaranteed to be null terminated'.

Comment: But what is "NTSTRSAFE_PWSTR" as required by the DDK?  Why not just "PWSTR" (wchar_t*)?

Comment: Updated with a reference to NTSTRSAFE_PWSTR. So the define just expands to include information for the static code analyzer.

Comment: In that case, may I say the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff562805(v=vs.85).aspx) is wrong? It uses LPTSTR in the declaration and never mentions that convention is not for kernel code and never references to NTSTRSAFE_PWSTR (exception in another UNICODE specific function RtlStringCchCopyUnicodeString)!!!